# Gradle Local Project Dependency

Tags: java, gradle

I have 2 Gradle projects both inside the same directory. The directory structure is as follows:

```
ParentDirectory\
    GradleProjectA\
        build.gradle
    GradleProjectB\
        settings.gradle
        build.gradle
```

I want to add `GradleProjectA` as a dependency to `GradleProjectB`. In the `settings.gradle` for `GradleProjectB`, I've tried adding `include 'GradleProjectA'` and then in `build.gradle`: `compile project(':GradleProjectA')` but that didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why didnt work? Which error do u get?

Comment: It just doesn't recognize GradleProjectA as a valid dependency.

Comment: Try replacing `include 'GradleProjectA'` for `include ':GradleProjectA'`

Comment: Tried that, also did not work.

Answer (score 28):

The way I did something like this is as follows:

`GradleProjectB/settings.gradle`:

```
include ':GradleProjectA'
project(':GradleProjectA').projectDir = new File('../GradleProjectA')
```

`GradleProjectB/build.gradle`:

```
compile project(":GradleProjectA")
```

Comment: By the way,  compile project(":GradleProjectA") needs to be to be inside the dependencies{....}  section of the build.gradle of ProjectB

Comment: Sorry it gives me error: `> Project with path ':ProjA' could not be found in project ':ProjB'.` Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

In the latest version of Gradle, you can use [Composite Builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html), like that:

In **GradleProjectB's settings.gradle**, add the following line:

`includeBuild "../GradleProjectA"`

It will automatically handle dependency collisions and all that stuff.

Comment: I want to use this trick on a project that is using a specific revision of another project that is waiting for a PR to be merged and so it hasn't been deployed yet (and so my project will have to wait for a while). I downloaded the _other_ project into my local and built it. Would this trick work in this case?

Answer (score 3):

The settings.gradle file needs to be in the parent directory specifying both.

Try the following format:

```
ParentDirectory\ 
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle <-- include 'GradleProjectA', 'GradleProjectB'
    GradleProjectA/
        build.gradle
    GradleProjectB/
        build.gradle
```

Edit:
Ok if your Parent Directory is not a build directory then you can do the following:

in your gradle project b settings.gradle file try the following:

```
includeFlat("GradleProjectA") // Include the project
```

in your b build.gradle:

```
compile project(":GradleProjectA")
```

[includeFlat reference](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html#org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings:includeFlat%28java.lang.String[]%29)

Comment: ParentDirectory isn't a Gradle project, it's just an empty IntelliJ project.

Comment: Update answer to account for non-gradle parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick:

```
root
+-- projectA
|   +-- build.gradle
|       => dependencies { compile project(':common') }
|   +-- settings.gradle 
|       => include ':common'
|          project(':common').projectDir = new File('../common')
+-- projectB
|   => same as projectA
+-- common
    +-- build.gradle
        => regular build, probably with a "jar" section
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `settings.gradle` in the parent directory. This just associates `GradleProjectA` with `GradleProjectB`. This is the approach used in the [official Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html). It would look like the following:

`ParentDirectory/settings.gradle`

```
rootProject.name = 'RootProject'
include 'GradleProjectA', 'GradleProjectB'
```

Then in `GradleProjectB/build.gradle`, you can simply write `implementation project(':GradleProjectA')` under dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

If `GradleProjectA` and `GradleProjectB` are part of one multi-project Gradle build, then you probably want the `settings.gradle` in `ParentDirectory` and there include A and B. The way you use `settings.gradle` is not correct. Maybe you should re-read the section about multi-project gradle builds in the User Guide.

If the two projects are indiviual projects but you still want to depend on A from B, you might prefer to build A, release it to some repository (possibly the mavenLocal repository) and then depend on the built artifacts from project B.