# How to use a Gradle dependency with local modifications?

Tags: android, gradle

I have an Android application using an Android library. The library is a pretty big open-source project on GitHub, and its authors publish the artifacts to Bintray. I can specify the dependency with the usual syntax `dependencies { implementation 'group:artifact:version' }` in the app's `build.gradle`.

Now I want to change some code in the library. I `git clone` it on my machine, I make my changes, then I build the library. But how can I tell my app to use the library I built locally, instead of the one in Bintray?

I don't want to follow the approach in [Gradle Local Project Dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479097/gradle-local-project-dependency), because that means that the library code is now part of the application project, but I really want to keep things separated.

I think the solution involves publishing to a local Maven repository. I followed the guide at https://proandroiddev.com/tip-work-with-third-party-projects-locally-with-gradle-961d6c9efb02 but the app's Gradle is still picking the original library from Bintray.

Answer (score 1):

Bintray-based projects have the `install` task. That's the one to be used instead of `publishToMavenLocal`.

When using `install`, the artifact version is automatically set to `X.X.X` before publishing to the local repository. Therefore, in order for the app to pick up the local library, you have to edit the `implementation` row to `group:artifact:X.X.X`.

As the guide https://proandroiddev.com/tip-work-with-third-party-projects-locally-with-gradle-961d6c9efb02 suggests, you also need to add `mavenLocal()` as the first entry in the `repositories` section in the top-level `build.gradle` of the application.