# Include a local library/ gradle project into Kotlin Multiplatform project

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, gradle-dependencies

Hello everyone I have a Kotlin Multiplatform project with a Common Module and Web-App. I currently need [Firebase Kotlin SDK](https://github.com/GitLiveApp/firebase-kotlin-sdk) as a dependency, but some features I had to modify. I forked the repository and published it locally (maven local) and included it in my project as the local version. Now I need to publish my web app and I need to have access to that version of that library.My question is

How can I include this project in my library? Or can I include the jars/ the published aars created from `gradlew publishMavenLocal` ?

I currently implement the dependency as
`implementation(dev.gitlive:firebase-auth:1.4.1-local)`

Ideally I'd just have something like
`implementation(project(firebase-kotlin-sdk:firebase-auth))`

I tried copying the entire repository into my root and added it in my settings.gradle `include("firebase-kotlin-sdk) // name of the module` but didn't work. Tried to `includeBuild()`` as well but didn't help.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov not entirely, but I'll try it, the question is quite old and I've tried most of the things they suggested

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52039513/3585796) is not that old, and also gradle is quite good at back compatibility, so old solutions should work fine