# How to add local dependency to project

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a project "A" in IntelliJ that has a Gradle dependency "B" (defined in "A"'s gradle.build). Both "A" and "B" source codes are in Bitbucket. I need to change some codes in "A" and "B". I had cloned both "A" and "B" repositories to my local. In IntelliJ, I want to remove "B" from "A"'s gradle.build, and then add "B"'s local directory as dependency of "A". How do I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479097/gradle-local-project-dependency

Comment: Some of the proposed solutions did not seem to work for the questioner. I am actually looking more of an IntelliJ solution since I am going to be working in IntelliJ.

Comment: IDEA uses gradle build file as initial project configuration. So all dependencies should be configured there.